# How to turn the result of a loop into a list, and then a variable?

Tags: python

I am working on hangman, and I need to turn the loop into a list for further code to work. What I have now is:

```
word = str(input('write a word here ')
wordLength = len(word)
for i in range(wordlength):
   print('_ ', end ='')
```

I want to have the underscores print, and be visible in the output (like they are now), but also create a list of that many underscores defined as 'userGuesses'.

Comment: your question is  not clear. Can you also include the expected output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
l = ['_' for char in word]
```

In python, you can iterate over the characters of a word just like over list items. So no need to determine `wordlength` and iterating over a range.

In the above example, you might get a warning about char being an unused variable. If this bothers you, replace variable name `char` with a variable name `_`. I avoided this here, as the underscore would have completely different meaning than the character `'_'`.

Comment: You miss the whitespace after underscore, as in OP question.

Comment: Nah, they shouldn't be in the list, but added when printing: `print(' '.join(l))`.